# Month, year selects no longer change after setDate onFocus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-select, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

Not a true duplicate of [jquery datepicker after setDate no longer able to change Month and Year in the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525436/jquery-datepicker-after-setdate-no-longer-able-to-change-month-and-year-in-the-h) since that's not setting on an event.

In my case, `setDate` on event renders the Month and Year unchangeable in the `select`s.

```
$("#addDeliverBy").off().datepicker({ 
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
}).focus(function(){
    $(this).datepicker( "setDate", "+7" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mqV2y/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `focus` event is being triggered every time you click something on the calendar, thereby calling `setDate` again.

If you're just trying to set the date when the datepicker is opened, using the `beforeShow` option is better here:

```
$("#addDeliverBy").off().datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    beforeShow: function () {
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", "+7");
    }
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/mqV2y/2/